# TDengine core dump with 300+ connections

Tags: concurrency, time-series, tdengine

Platform OS:CentOS 7.0]
TDengine Version [e.g. 20.0.20.10]

When I use 300 more concurrent connections to connect TDengine, its core is dumped.

Pretty simple using:
TAOS *taos = taos_connect("td1", "root", "taosdata", "testdb", 6030);

```
(gdb) where
#0 0x00007fb2b0934f81 in pthread_join (threadid=140404954195712, thread_return=0x7ffea3944d80) at pthread_join.c:92
#1 0x00007fb2b061ec03 in taosStopTcpThread (pThreadObj=0x137b0b0) at
/home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/rpc/src/rpcTcp.c:188
#2 0x00007fb2b061f8d5 in taosCleanUpTcpClient (chandle=0x137ab50) at
/home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/rpc/src/rpcTcp.c:384
#3 0x00007fb2b061f801 in taosInitTcpClient (ip=0, port=0, label=0x135c084 "TSC", numOfThreads=40, fp=0x7fb2b061b2cc
, shandle=0x135c070)
at /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/rpc/src/rpcTcp.c:365
#4 0x00007fb2b06185f0 in rpcOpen (pInit=0x7ffea3943230) at
/home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/rpc/src/rpcMain.c:308
#5 0x00007fb2b03ca1fe in tscAcquireRpc (key=0x7ffea3943820 "root:taosdata:td1:6030", user=0x42e8ea "root",
secretEncrypt=0x7ffea39437d0 "\334ž\320HQ\376\310T\300\065\262\344\002c\266", ppRpcObj=0x7ffea3943500)
at /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/client/src/tscSystem.c:101
#6 0x00007fb2b03ae4ff in taosConnectImpl (ip=0x42e8ef "td1", user=0x42e8ea "root", pass=0x42e8e1 "taosdata", auth=0x0,
db=0x42e8da "testdb", port=6030,
fp=0x7fb2b03ae94e , param=0x0, taos=0x7ffea3943a98) at
/home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/client/src/tscSql.c:99
#7 0x00007fb2b03aea12 in taos_connect_internal (ip=0x42e8ef "td1", user=0x42e8ea "root", pass=0x42e8e1 "taosdata",
auth=0x0, db=0x42e8da "testdb", port=6030)
at /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/client/src/tscSql.c:189
#8 0x00007fb2b03aec57 in taos_connect (ip=0x42e8ef "td1", user=0x42e8ea "root", pass=0x42e8e1 "taosdata", db=0x42e8da
"testdb", port=6030)
at /home/ubuntu/workroom/jenkins/TDinternal/community/src/client/src/tscSql.c:226
#9 0x000000000040720a in main (argc=22, argv=0x7ffea3944d88) at SpxACodeDemo0.15.cpp:385
```

Anyone experience such an issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you show us the client log, where mostly under `/var/log/taos/` and with the name `taoslogx.x`. You can grep the ERROR messages in those log files.